# The constructor should be payable if you send value ? It seems no error on my code

Tags: solidity, remix

I am a student who studies solidity now. I am following the tutorial now to study how to write solidity code on Remix. But I think below code does not have any problem, but it keeps making an error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Receive {
    uint256 public balance;
    function pay() public payable {

    }
}

contract Send {
    Receive public r;

    constructor() public {
        r = new Receive();
    }

    function send() public payable {
        address(r).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
The constructor should be payable if you send value
```

But if I remove the name of payable fallback function in Receive contract like below:

```
function () public payable {

}
```

It works. but why this happens ..? and the tutorial says that payable fallback function can have its name and also the statements in it, too.

Comment: The fallback function should be nameless (unfortunately; forcing the name `send` would actually be very much appropriate IMO).

Comment: But, this code works properly on Remix. https://pastebin.com/LCnf5Bb6
the bid() function is a fallback function, but it has its name.

Comment: And even send() function in Send contract is a fallback function. But it has the name “send”.

Comment: There's some confusion here. The "fallback function" is specifically the (optional) function with no name. `send()` is not a fallback function because it has a name. But there's no reason there has to be a fallback function. (In fact, I regularly argue against having one.)

Comment: The issue is that `send()` calls `address(r).transfer(msg.value)`. This sends a message with no data to `Receive`, which means it triggers `Receive`'s fallback function. Unfortunately, it doesn't have one, and the default implementation is to revert if ether is sent to a non-existent fallback function. If you want to call the function `pay()` on `Receive`, just use `r.pay.value(msg.value)()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a payable fallback function. The function pay would be fine, but you aren't calling it via something like `address(r).pay.value(msg.value);`. Instead you're just doing `address(r).transfer(msg.value)`, and to do this, the contract you're calling needs to have a payable fallback, i.e. a payable function that has no name.